# Changing Property Attributes Via Utility functions

Tags: javascript

I have following piece of JavaScript code

```
function freezeProps(o) {
var props = (arguments.length == 1) // If 1 arg
? Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o) // use all props
: Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments, 1); // else named props
props.forEach(function(n) { // Make each one read-only and permanent
// Ignore nonconfigurable properties
if (!Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o,n).configurable) return;
Object.defineProperty(o, n, { writable: false, configurable: false });
});
   return o; // So we can keep using it
}

// Make the named (or all) properties of o nonenumerable, if configurable.
  function hideProps(o) {
  var props = (arguments.length == 1) // If 1 arg
  ? Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o) // use all props
  : Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments, 1); // else named props
   props.forEach(function(n) { // Hide each one from the for/in loop
  // Ignore nonconfigurable properties
   if (!Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o,n).configurable) return;
   Object.defineProperty(o, n, { enumerable: false });
  });
     return o;
   }


 function Range(from, to) { // Constructor for an immutable Range class
      this.from = from;
      this.to = to;
       freezeProps(this); // Make the properties immutable
 }

Range.prototype = hideProps({ // Define prototype with nonenumerable   properties
 constructor: Range,
 includes: function(x) { return this.from <= x && x <= this.to; },
  foreach: function(f) {for(var x=Math.ceil(this.from);x<=this.to;x++)    f(x);},
  toString: function() { return "(" + this.from + "..." + this.to + ")"; }
 });

  var range = new Range(10, 12);
  var result = range.includes(10.9666);
  alert(result);
```

What I'm not able to understand in both the functions freezeProps() and hideProps() is that lets say that I pass in more than one argument to hideProps(arg1,arg2,arg3) then

```
  arguments.length != 1
```

and  the following line of code will be executed

```
 var props =  Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments, 1);
```

But props will contain a resulting array like [arg2,arg3] if that is the case then how come one can still change named properties (as is clear from the comments in the code) on object arg1 to nonenumerable. This is not making sense to me. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Because you use `Object.defineProperty(o, ...)`

Comment: I tried that though "o" will be as is but the values of "n" inside the forEach callback function(n) will be arg2 and arg3, which throws an error saying that "Unable to get property 'configurable' of undefined or null reference".